# SpriteKit present scene new scene appears in wrong place

Tags: sprite-kit

I am trying to build  game in spriteKit and I want it to start with a menu and when the user touches the play button the game scene should be presented, which happens, but the gameScene appears in the wrong place, see attached image. When I start the game directly on the gameScene it appears in the correct place.
The code that is commented is code I have tested, but with the same result.

```
class StartScene: SKScene {
    
    var myScreenSize: Int = 0
    
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var currentScreenSize = 0
    
    
    
    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dogbone")
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Baskerville-Bold")

      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
          
          if screenSize.width == 812 && screenSize.height == 375 {
              currentScreenSize = 1
          } else if screenSize.width == 736 && screenSize.height == 414 {
              currentScreenSize = 2
          } else if screenSize.width == 667 && screenSize.height == 375 {
              currentScreenSize = 3
          } else if screenSize.width == 736 && screenSize.height == 414 {
              currentScreenSize = 4
          } else if screenSize.width == 568 && screenSize.height == 320 {
              currentScreenSize = 5
          } else if screenSize.width == 1366 && screenSize.height == 1024 {
              currentScreenSize = 6
          } else if screenSize.width == 834 && screenSize.height == 1112 {
              currentScreenSize = 7
          } else if screenSize.width == 1024 && screenSize.height == 768 {
              currentScreenSize = 8
          }
          
          print("screen current \(currentScreenSize)")
          
          print("screen \(myScreenSize)")
          myLabel.fontColor = UIColor.black
          myLabel.position.y = 230
          myLabel.text = "HEJSAN"
          addChild(myLabel)

          //addChild(gameTitle)
          
          //playButton.position.y = 230
          playButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
          
          addChild(playButton)
      }
    
    /// Touches began
    override open func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {
            let pos = touch.location(in: self)
            let node = self.atPoint(pos)

            if node == playButton {
                if let viewCurrent = view {
                    let transition: SKTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
                    //let scene: SKScene = GameScene(size: self.size)
                    let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height))
                    
                    
//                    scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
//                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
//                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
//                    scene.scaleMode = .fill
                    viewCurrent.presentScene(scene)
                    
//                    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
//                    let skView = viewCurrent as! SKView
//                    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
//                    skView.presentScene(scene)
                    
//                    let skview = self.view?.scene?.view
//                    skview?.presentScene(scene)
                    
                    //viewCurrent.presentScene(scene)
                    
                    
                    
                    //self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
                    //self.view?.presentScene(scene)
                }
            }
        }
  }   
}
```

[Image shows where the scene appears, in the lower left corner instead of full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fjnI.jpg)

Comment: Remove the code you commented out to make it easier for people to read the code listing. Also take a look at the Related questions on the right side of the page. There are several questions about presenting SpriteKit scenes that could help you.

Comment: Check the Anchorpoint settings in the GameScene.sks file (Editor)